# Can the blog creation time on wordpress.com be determined?

Tags: wordpress, webarchive, wordpress.com, alexa-internet

Is it possible to write a blog in wordpress.com today and give it a date of another time in the past?

Another question is how do I find when a blog in http://wordpress.com/ was created? By saying blog I meant a user's blog with a URL like user.wordpress.com.

Comment: Certainly in self-hosted WP you can choose any date you like - whether blogs at wordpress.com permit that I am not sure. Why not create one and try it? Or, ask their support channels - the question is probably a bit too localised for here. As for your second question, unless a blog is marked in some way as having a creation date, I am not sure you can tell. If you have a particular one in mind, can you just ask the author(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is it possible to write a blog in wordpress.com today and give it a date of another time in the past?`
That's possible.

`Another question is how do I find when a blog in http://wordpress.com/ was created? By saying blog I meant a user's blog with a URL like user.wordpress.com.`
By going to http://en.forums.wordpress.com/profile/wordpress-username